# Why am I getting System.OutOfMemory Exception when running .NET Core 2.1 on Alpine?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, alpine-linux

Using the .NET Core 2.1.1 Alpine (the SDK and the runtime) leads to several errors:

A. Fatal Internal connection when connecting to an SQL Server Database
B. After a few hours, the app boxes throw System.OutOfMemory exceptions regardless of the load and the available processing power.

Answer (score 3):

If you get this, then you're out of luck! Please do not make the same mistake as we did with adopting Alpine-based NETCore 2.1 for what's about to become a production-ready app in a few months. After weeks of hunting weird bugs, we came to realise that .NET Core 2.1 in the Alpine falvor is fully experimental. Basic functionality is hindered by gross bugs. One can only wonder the range of detailed, more context-specific bugs that you're likely to encounter in production.

A. You'll need to install the icu-libs package. Connecting a .NET app to an SQL Server database is probably the most popular db connection of the language. One would think that the .NET team would test that their spanking new Alpine images so that MVC apps can properly connect to, but no. The 2.1.1 runtime image cannot automatically convert Windows string format to Linux ones.

Here's a link showing that Microsoft is aware of the issue but does not list this as a known bug:

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/29147

B. Turns out that the 2.1.1 Alpine-based runtime for .NET Core is having some serious memory leaks. Microsoft's own .NET team is fully aware of the issues:

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/30652

Sadly, however, the .NET team appears to be hiding the problems in the Github discussions. Plenty of users have signaled similar errors but instead of letting devs know that the 2.1.1 Alpine-based runtime image is severely broken, it looks like the issue is just covered up by Microsoft. Please note that the issue is not listed among the known issues of .NET Core 2.1.

Comment: For issue A the workaround is to set [DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/560#issuecomment-393521140) to false, but that didn't help you?  For issue B it seems that the current workaround is to drop back to 2.1.0, or is that not an option?